# "Other platform" configuration in Firebase dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When [creating a dynamic link manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) there is a `ofl` parameter for "other platforms". It handles this use case:

> The link to open on platforms beside Android and iOS. This is useful to specify a different behavior on desktop, like displaying a full web page of the app content/payload (as specified by param link) with another dynamic link to install the app.

However when using the [`shortLinks` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) directly all the other configuration is present *except* the other platform configuration (and iOS minimum version parameter).

Is this just an oversight in the documentation, or is there no way to specify this parameter in the `shortLinks` endpoint. Must I create a long link manually and then shorten it?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way I found in order to have the OFL params is by:

1. Create a long link with all your params
2. Append `&ofl=[YOUR_LINK]` at the end of the link
3. Create a short link with the long link

Here is an example:

```
  const link = [YOUR_LINK];
  const domainUriPrefix = [YOUR_DOMAIN_URI_PREFIX];
  const ios = [YOUR_IOS_PARAMS];
  const android = [YOUR_ANDROID_PARAMS];
  const social = [YOUR_SOCIAL_PARAMS];
  let uncompressURL = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
    link,
    domainUriPrefix,
    ios,
    android,
    social
  });
  uncompressURL += "&ofl=[YOUR_OFL_LINK]";
  let compressURL = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
    link: uncompressURL,
    domainUriPrefix,
  });
```

The downside of this solution is that you have two redirection instead of one...